# Not able to ping windows machine using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and trying to connect to windows machine using Ansible. 
I am getting following error

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "plaintext: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x3d76050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",
"unreachable": true
```

}

I have made changes in these three files.

1. Inventory:

   [windows]
   xxx.xxx.xxx.com
2. Krb5.conf

   [realms]
   XXX.XXX.COM = {
    kdc = xxx.xxx.xxx.com
    admin_server = xxx.xxx.xxx.com
   }
   [domain_realm]
   .xxx.xxx.com = XXX.XXX.COM
3. group_vars/windows.yml

   ansible_ssh_user: user
   ansible_ssh_pass: password
   ansible_ssh_port: 5985
   ansible_connection: winrm

I am new to this and may have made mistake in the process of connectivity.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be certain, you've setup the winrm features on the Windows machines in the inventory, right?  ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#getting-to-powershell-3-0-or-higher )

Comment: No I didn't but i am going to do that. I tried { ansible windows -i hosts -m ping} too which is also returning the same error.

Comment: the "-m ping" actually uses ssh, it's not a traditional ICMP ping.  Since Windows uses "winrm" instead of "ssh" that would be why the "-m ping" fails on Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

The msg key says "plaintext", you need to enable winrm over ssl on the windows hosts with this PowerShell script provided by ansible:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

Since that will add a self signed certificate be sure to add `ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore` to your group_vars/windows.yml